# jQuery select2 reformats <select> but submits the option ID instead of the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) jquery plugin to reformat my long select options. Everything works as expected, except when I submit the form the the `id` value gets saved as the value, instead of the value (in this case `lang`). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what the script looks like:

```
var langs=[{id:0,lang:'English'},
    {id:1,lang:'Afrikaans'},
    {id:2,lang:'Albanian'},
    {id:3,lang:'Zulu'}];

function format(item) { return item.lang; };

$("#field_4").select2({
                  placeholder: "Select your language",
                  data:{ results: langs, text: 'lang' },
                  formatSelection: format,
                  formatResult: format
                  });
```

Here's the markup:

```
<input id="field_4" name="field_4" type="text" class="regular-text " value="3" />
```

When I log the return value in the console I see this:

```
{Object}
    O: Object
        id: "1"
        text: "Afrikaans"
```

**UPDATE:**
I made some progress on this. If I add the following to the constructor object (for select2) I can save the correct values (instead of the `id`). However this doesn't work when I add to the `<select>`s that use AJAX to get the options.

```
id : function(object) {
return object.lang;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it *supposed* to save the id? That *is* the value; the `lang` is the text, not the value.

Comment: I want the form to save the actual language name. Not the id. Is this possible?

Comment: Then why even have ids? Or should I say, have only ids (but make them the language names) and set the "text" value to 'id' instead of 'text'.

Comment: @JohnS Your hack would probably work, but the ID property is expected when the options list is piped in by AJAX, which is what I'm doing elsewhere in the form. I left the AJAX out of this question because I'm having the same problem on all my inputs, so the AJAX isn't the problem. But I still need to figure out the right way assign the correct value.

Comment: @JohnS It turns out select2 always wants the ID property included. I tested it with just the `text:` and it makes the options unelectable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out with the assistance of the developer: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/852#issuecomment-13478644

In short, there's an `id:` callback function which handles mapping the returned ID to the desired input value.

Comment: Thanks for the 'in-short' b/c the link no longer exists