# Select2 shows TEXT but submits IDs, using with Flask, WTForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jquery-select2, flask-wtforms

I'am trying to implement the Select2 drop-down (data via ajax) feature while using WTForms. Almost everything is working, meaning data is being fetched properly and processed in the expected 'ID and TEXT' format that Select2 expects.

However I am getting a "Not a valid choice" error upon submitting - when `validate_on_submit` is run. This appears to be caused by the fact that Select2 is submitting the ID number and not the TEXT. This is weird because it is displaying the text on the page itself when searching and actually making the selection.`validate_on_submit` is expecting 0 or 1 and not a random integer which is why it throws and error. How do I workaround this? How do I get the actual TEXT submitted?

And also any text/selection in previous Select2 fields disappears when adding a line or deleting one (I guess when running `render_template`??). Choices that are specified in flask/python are left intact as they should.

The most similar questions I could find are [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182187/how-to-populate-a-wtforms-selectfield-with-an-ajax-call-i-e-select2) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271433/why-is-my-flask-form-validation-returning-not-a-valid-choice) but either there is no answer or I am unable to fully understand and apply it.

Here is some of the code:

**Javascript**

```
$(element).parents('.row').find('.item-model').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option',
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/1/modelsnew',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: function (params) {
            var specificquery = {
            name: params.term
            }
            return specificquery;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
                var res = data.models.map(function (item) {
                    return {id: item.hardware_id, text: item.name};
                });
            return {
                results: res
            };
        },
        cache: true
   },
   minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-3">
{{ line.item_model.label}}
{% if line.item_model.data == 'Software' %}
{{ line.item_model(class='form-control item-model', disabled=true) }}
{% else %}
{{ line.item_model(class='form-control item-model') }}
{% endif %}
{% for error in line.item_model.errors %}
<p class="form-control-status text-danger">
    {{ error }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Flask-WTForm**

```
class DeviceForm(FlaskForm):
    item_model = SelectField('MODEL', choices=[('0', 'Select Item')], validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Further looking into this it appears the same issues are described here [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823958/jquery-select2-reformats-select-but-submits-the-option-id-instead-of-the-value) and [question4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935066/previous-fields-text-disappears-when-adding-new-one-with-select2-ajax) but I am still unable to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

I can also provide a gif and/or screenshots.

**UPDATE**:

I found out how to 'get' the TEXT value and display it via console.log but how do I make this the selection for the WTForms SelectField ? Why would it register the ID on submit?

```
var hereitgoes = $(element).parents('.row').find('.item-model')    
$(hereitgoes).on("select2:select", function (e) { 
var selectedtext = $(e.currentTarget).text();
console.log(selectedtext)
});
```